# Super slow pc startup and continues freezing

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I started to notice that my Windows 7 PC was running super slow and everything I opened would say `not responding` after a few seconds.

I performed a format and re-install of Windows, defragged my hard drive, and ran a registry cleaner.  Nothing has helped.  Even on start up my PC is super slow.

My ram is running at 30% and there is no high CPU usage at all.  This is really frustrating and I can't do any work because of this.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you've reformatted the hard drive and done a clean install of windows then I am afraid to say that the issue is most likely due to some hardware malfunction in your system. I would recommend backing up your important data now and taking it into a shop to try to determine where the problem is coming from. The only other option is to invest in a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sad to hear about your condition.

I think you should install a genuine windows 7 having a 32bit version which is lightweight compared to 64bit.

Using an SSD would probably solve your issue in seconds.

If still nothing works for you, try using a good [PC Cleaner](https://cyberlab.com/) and remove all your junk files, cache, registry errors, etc. Hope this helps.